# Image not uploading to firebase storage correctly using the emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage, firebase-tools

My emulator is set up and running, however, when I exercise the below function my image does not show up in the storage emulator as expected. I am consistently met with an image the size of 9B - broken/no preview. The path is correct /users/UID/profileImage.png.

All images I have tested are larger than 9B and all of them upload to the storage emulator using the emulator UI with no problem - preview showing and correct size.

Can anyone please help troubleshoot my code to see if anything is wrong here?

```
file.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user, selectedFile) {
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener('load', function () {
                img.setAttribute('src', reader.result);
            });

            reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);

            const metadata = {
                contentType: 'image/png'
            };

            // make ref to your firebase storage and create image for user
            var storageRef = ref(storage, 'users/' + auth.currentUser.uid + '/profileImage.png');

            // put file to firebase 
            var uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);

            uploadTask.on(
                'state_changed',
                (snapshot) => {
                    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                    progressBar.style.width = `${progress}%`;
                    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
                    switch (snapshot.state) {
                        case 'paused':
                            console.log('Upload is paused');
                            break;
                        case 'running':
                            console.log('Upload is running');
                            break;
                    }
                }, (error) => {
                    switch (error.code) {
                        case 'storage/unauthorized':
                            // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                            alert('User has no permission');
                            break;
                        case 'storage/canceled':
                            // User canceled the upload
                            alert('Upload was cancelled');
                            break;
                        case 'storage/unknown':
                            // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
                            alert(error);
                            break;
                    }
                }, () => {
                    // handle upload success
                    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                        img.src = downloadURL;
                        var user = auth.currentUser;
                        updateProfile(user, { photoURL: downloadURL })
                            .then(function () { console.log(user) })
                            .catch(function (error) { console.log(error) });
                    });
                    document.getElementById('submit_link').removeAttribute('disabled');
                });
        } else {
            console.log(`user doc could not be updated`);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: I am also running into this issue. Did you ever find a fix for this?